# Is it possible to do (new Thing())() for some Thing?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-programming

Essentially, what I want is to have the `this` within Thing's constructor to be a function (but `instanceof Thing` of course). Is this possible?

Comment: i am not sure i understood your question.Are you looking at something like this http://jsbin.com/fisug/1/edit

Comment: @Runner: I think so, but that won’t result in a `new Thing() instanceof Thing === true`.

Answer (score 0):

No. Native functions are the only callable.

Comment: I would like to accept your answer. Is there documentation/specification for this?

Comment: @beardtree: The ES5 spec doesn’t say this specifically, unfortunately, but I’m 99.9% sure it’s true for ES5 and current ES6. (See https://es5.github.io/#x9.11; functions have `[[Call]]`, but it’s not stated in the specification that *only* functions can have it. And it’s *not* true, either, in practice – `typeof` on host object methods in IE8 and earlier results in `'object'`, and this is standards-compliant, but you can’t create host objects in user code.)

Answer (score 0):

Functions cannot have prototype chains other than `Function.prototype`, and a function cannot be an object's prototype.

So instances of a class cannot be callable, and functions cannot inherit from a class.

I too have come across scenarios where I thought this would be useful, but found it didn't work.